# Delphi TWebModule (IIS-ISAPI): get the current request

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

in a `TWebModule` procedure/function how get the current request?

I have tried:

```
procedure TWebModule1.DoSomething;
var 
  aRequest : TWebRequest;
begin
  aRequest := Request;
end;
```

but it seems the first request produced on `TWebModule` creation.

I know i'm able to pass the request to subsequent Procedures/Functions from each `TWebActionItem`, but i want avoid to pass the request every where. Any tips?

**Update**

After digging into the code, i found WebContext and it seems the solution, eg.:

```
uses Web.WebCntxt;

procedure TWebModule1.DoSomething;
var
  aRequest : TWebRequest;
begin
  if WebContext <> nil then
    aRequest := WebContext.Request;
end;
```

is it the right way? `WebContext` seems always `nil`.

I'm on Delphi Berlin update 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Request goes through a `TWebActionItem` defined in the `TWebModule.Actions`. The `TWebActionItem` has an event `OnAction`. There you will get the `TWebRequest` Object of the current Request.

Then you are able to pass it to subsequent Procedures/Functions.

Comment: yes, but i want avoid to pass the request every where

Comment: I think every request will be handled in a separate thread. So you should pass it to avoid thread-conflicts. You could also store it as a Class-Field. But then you have to handle multi-threads.

Comment: You could make it a threadvar like SOAP or Datasnap webmodules do.

Comment: @OndrejKelle you can make a practical example in a separate answer? there is an open bounty on the question.

Comment: @SimoneNigro Please make clear which version of Delphi you're using. The tag is delphi-xe but in the question you mention Berlin update 2. Which is it?

Comment: You can simply access the [`Request`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Web.HTTPApp.TCustomWebDispatcher.Request) property of your `TWebModule` descendant as you have shown in your question. This property always refers to the current request. If you observe different behaviour please provide a MCVE.